# How do I make Math.random pick the same amount of user input value from 4 different arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, user-input

Good evening smart people!

I am new to programming and I need your help! I got stuck at this code challenge and would love some input on how I can go about this. How do I make Math.random pick the same amount of user input value from 4 different arrays? I am pretty sure the math.random I wrote is wrong. I hit a wall. Thank you ahead for helping! I think this is how you would go about it; By combining the 4 arrays into one array and somehow make the method Math.random pick the random value of what the user input in a prompt. Thank you once again!

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [A, B, C];
let array3 = [a, b, c];
let array4 = [%, @. ^];

let fourArray[array1, array2, array3, array4];

let dnumConfirm = confirm("Do you want numbers in your password?");
let capConfirm = confirm("Do you wantn capital letters in your password?");
let lowConfirm = confirm("Do you want lowercase letters in your password?");
let specialConfirm = confirm("Do you want special characters in your           password?");
let userInput = parseInt(prompt("How many capital letters would you like?"));
function random(userInput) {
 
  
if(dnumConfirm && capConfirm && lowConfirm && specialConfirm) {
     const randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random * Math.floor(userInput(fourArray))); 
     return randomValue; 
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what "pick the same amount of user input value from 4 different arrays" means please?

Comment: So, I throw a prompt and I type in an integer of 14. I want Math.random method to pick 14 characters from 4 arrays. So I figured you put those 4 arrays into one array. I hope that made sense.

Comment: Hey, so I added an answer and could you check to see if that is what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = ["A", "B", "C"];
let array3 = ["a", "b", "c"];
let array4 = ["%", "@". "^"];

let fourArray = [...array1, ...array2, ...array3, ...array4];

let dnumConfirm = confirm("Do you want numbers in your password?");
let capConfirm = confirm("Do you wantn capital letters in your password?");
let lowConfirm = confirm("Do you want lowercase letters in your password?");
let specialConfirm = confirm("Do you want special characters in your           password?");
let userInput = parseInt(prompt("How many capital letters would you like?"));

function random(userInput) {   
     if(dnumConfirm && capConfirm && lowConfirm && specialConfirm) {
          let randomValue = "";
          for (let i = 0; i < userInput; i++)
               randomValue += userInput[Math.floor(Math.random() * fourArray.length)]; 
          return randomValue; 
     }
}
```

Made your `array2`, `array3`, `array4` to strings.
Changed `fourArray` to a one dimensional array by spreading the other arrays.
Also I made a loop that would create random string in your `random` function.
Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

We can generate a random integer from 0 to N using both  `Math.random` and `Math.floor` using the formula:
`Math.floor(Math.random() * (N + 1))`

First create an empty array to hold the other arrays.

```
let charTypes = [];
```

As the user selects a type of character (lowercase letters etc), add the corresponding array to charTypes with push.
Example: `charTypes.push(array3);`

Save the length of this array to a variable.

```
let differentKinds = charTypes.length;
```

Use a loop to iterate over the total number of characters, `userInput`, and select a random integer on [0, differentKinds -1].

```
let password = ''; 
for(let i = 0; i < userInput; i++){
    // get index on [0, differentKinds - 1]
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (differentKinds));
    
    //Use the array charTypes[j] take a random index on [0,2]. 
    let k = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);  
    
    // We can now concatenate a random character with charTypes[j][k]
    password += charTypes[j][k]; 
}
```